# How to enrich message in File Route from SFTP to JMS in clustered environment using Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, integration, camel-ftp, header-enricher

We are going to read a file from SFTP and put employees in database.

Following is XML Structure

```
 <employees>
     <employee></employee>
     <employee></employee>
     <employee></employee>
 <employees>
```

The strategy i think is:

1. Pick XML file from SFTP ->
2. Fetch Employee No. from XML -> (24000 Employees)
3. Fetch Data from "System 1 and System 2" on base of employee no. in xml file all together in memory ->
4. Split Employee from XML ->
5. Assign Data from "System 1 and System 2" to Each employee Exchange ->
6. Put Each employee XML to JMS Queue (Read in clustered envionment)

Is there any other best strategy to handle this scenario in Apache Camel in abve route or route 2 (Jms Queue)?

Note: As it is clustered environment; we can't fetch data from System1 & System2 in servers itself then we need to keep tracking by assigning batch id to one file contents. You can think this scenario in other integrations too

Comment: What is the relationship between "Data" and employee/XML File?

Comment: @hk6279: Updated scenario. It is employee data fetched on base of ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above steps can be improved by

1. Speed up your process after step 4 by parallel processing (e.g. use threadpool)
2. Fasten SFTP process by release core thread after step 3 (e.g. use wireTap)

   - To prevent data lost, store exchange to another persistent storage (e.g. JMS queue)
   - The application's memory usage will increase

If step 3 (fetch data from "System 1 and System 2") can be done concurrently, launch multiple application instance with idempotent (leverage external cache or DB) might help for lots of files.

Comment: Thanks for insights. What should be scenario if 5 becomes 4 and 4 becomes 5?

Comment: This depends on the nature of data assignment. If data are assigned base on full set/list of employee, the parallel processing will be impossible. If data are assigned base on each employee, keep your current approach.

Comment: OK
Data is coming in XML. So thinking of reading xml then fetching employee id and fetch related data from systems and enrich xml and send further to body.split() method which further send to streaming().inOnly(Queue). Not sure if this is good way

Comment: In case you can achieve your goal (with acceptable speed and memory usage and any other factor you concern), it is good enough solution